# Operating on exiting data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've got some code something like this:

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

var dataMap = {
    1 : 'a',
    2 : 'b',
    3 : 'c',
    4 : 'd',
    5 : 'e',
    6 : 'f',
    7 : 'g',
    8 : 'h',
    9 : 'i',
    10 : 'j'
}

var root = d3.select('#myDiv').selectAll('div').data(data, function(d){return d;})
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .text(function(d){ return dataMap[d] });

var newData = [2,3,4,6,7,8];

var select = root.selectAll('div').data(newData, function(d){ return d; });
```

I need to delete the divs that no longer exist, but first, I need to operate on the data associated with the exiting divs, like this:

```
exitingData.each(function(d){ dataMap.delete[d]; });
```

I'm having trouble getting the array `exitingData`, which I'd like to be an array of all of the data that I initially bound to my divs whose IDs aren't in the new data coming in. Is there a way to obtain the obsolete data when I'm entering new data? I tried this, which doesn't work:

```
exit.each(function(d){ console.log(d); console.log('ran!') });
```

Here's the fiddle I'm working with: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckersch/f5dM2/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want. Basically, I am printing the exiting divs' text to the console.

```
function update(dataset) {
    var root = d3.select('#myDiv')
        .selectAll('div')
        .data(dataset, function(d){return d;});

    // enter selection
    root
      .enter()
        .append('div');

    // update selection
    root
        .text(function(d){ return dataMap[d] });

    // capturing the exit selection
    var rootExit = root.exit();

    // using the exit selection before removal
    // i.e. printing exiting div text to console
    rootExit.each(function(d){ console.log(d3.select(this).text()) });

    // finally removing elements
    rootExit
      .remove();
};
```

Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LqEyA/).